# Cast classes to classes with generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am reflectively getting classes and their declared classes, and I want to pass them into a function that takes classes, but it has generics on it.

```java
// classes to pass into function
ClassPath.from(MyParent.class.getClassLoader())
  .getTopLevelClasses()
  .forEach(classInfo -> {
    // checks...

    Class<?> clazz = classInfo.load();
    for (Class<?> declaredClass : clazz.getDeclaredClasses()) {
      genericFunction(clazz, declaredClass); // the problem
    }

  });
```

```java
// the function to pass into
<E extends Extendable<? extends Parent<E>>> void genericFunction(Class<? extends Parent<E>> parentClass, Extendable<E> extendableClass);
```

```java
// classes used in generic function
public class MyParent extends Parent<MyExtendable> {
  protected class MyExtendable extends Extendable<MyParent> {
    
  }
}

public abstract class Parent<E extends Extendable<? extends Parent<E>>> {
  
}

public abstract class Extendable<E extends Parent<? extends Extendable<E>>> {
  
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to cast or reflective run that `genericFunction()` with the `Class<?>` objects.

I can assume that the classes that [`ClassPath`](https://guava.dev/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) finds are compatible (e.g: they all properly extend `Parent` and `Extendable` in inner classes.)

I can change my (likely) messy and overcomplicated generics on the function and classes.

Comment: "I can assume that the classes that ClassPath finds are compatible". I find this very hard to believe. Did you do some filtering that you omitted from your question?

Comment: @Sweeper where `MyPacket` is, the other classes there are what I've made myself and I can confirm they are compatible. I know what classes will be passed to the function, I just want it to be done _reflectively_.

Comment: Your declared classes are `Class<? extends Extendable<E>>`, not `Extendable<E>`. That or make an instance with `declaredClass.getConstructor().newInstance()`. Note that this is all quite bad code abuse and you should not be doing it this way. Class Loading's abstraction doesn't work this way. Idiomatic java isn't anything like this. Etcetera.

Comment: The right solution to what you're badly trying to solve with that ClassPath.from stuff (abolish that library, it's just wrong - the ClassLoader abstraction doesn't let you do this, it's a hack that won't work in various environments) - is SPI/module-provides.

Comment: I second what rzwitserloot said.  You should be using [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for this.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. As service loaders have been recommended, how can I implement this in relation to what I'm doing?